# php генерация qrcode с кирилицей

Tags: php, qr, qrcode

Генерирую qr с помощью либы phpqrcode. Сохраняю в файл.

Вот код генерации (переменный в строке представляют собой инт и флоат числа)

```
$codeContents = 'ST00012|PersonalAcc=40702810700000303331|BIC=047516949|CorrespAcc=30101810700000000949|PAYEEINN=7414000495|PersAcc='.$ls.'|PaymPeriod=20191001|Sum='.$cost.'|BankName="КУБ"ОАО"|Name=МП трест "Водоканал" МО г.Магнитогорск';


    QRcode::png($codeContents, "QRfile.png","L", 4);
```

Но при сканирование получаю это

ST00012|PersonalAcc=40702810700000303331|BIC=047516949|CorrespAcc=30101810700000000949|PAYEEINN=7414000495|PersAcc=0801000018|PaymPeriod=20191001|Sum=575.55|BankName="КУБ"ОАО"|Name=МП трест "Водокан?

Понятное дело что дело в кодировке, но не знаю как ее решить, попробовал несколько функций перекодировки в utf-8, не вышло.

Если посоветуете другую библиотеку, то нужно что бы в ней было сохранение в файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинку покажите

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Используйте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php с первым параметром “UTF-8”, и её результат кладите в QR.